# How to add jump links wordpress navigation bar?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How to add jump links wordpress navigation bar ? I want to create a item in navbar which when clicked jumps to footer .

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with something like this:

```
<a href="#footer">Footer</a>
```

And in your footer's div add this `id="footer"`